# minute and second in working with degree

Tags: geometry

A degree is shown by 21°37'3".
I want to transform it into radians in order to do mathematical operations on it. I do not know how to do so.
Please explain how I can transform such number into radians. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform from hexagesimal notation to fractional parts of degrees: $$21^ \circ 37'3'' = (21+\frac{37}{60}+\frac 3{3600})^\circ $$
then use the factor $\frac{\pi\text{ rad}}{180^\circ}$ to convert to radians.

Comment: @Hagen What do you think, the minute and seconds thing is useless, isn't it? I do not why it is still incorporated into courses? You cannot do any mathematical process with it without converting it tediously, and no one uses them anyway?

Answer (score 2):

A minute is 1/60 of a degree, and a second is 1/60 of a minute (like time). Use that to scale 1 degree = $\pi$/180 radians.